# Remove duplicate parent node based on child node and add specific element values in the concerning node

Tags: xslt

I want to sum the value's "TotalAmount" and "Tax" with //Category/ID as unique value. The XSLT has to delete the duplicate(s) and sum the values of the deleted duplicate. So for this example, the unique ID "S" is a duplicate and should be deleted and the required values should be added to the other "S". I'm not able to make the XSLT working.

Input example:

```
   <root>
    <Total>
      <TotalAmount currencyID="EUR">100.00</TotalAmount>
      <Tax currencyID="EUR">20.00</Tax>
      <Category>
        <ID>S</ID>
        <Percent>21.000</Percent>
        <Description>
          <ID>Note</ID>
        </Description>
      </Category>
    </Total>
    <Total>
      <TotalAmount currencyID="EUR">150.00</TotalAmount>
      <Tax currencyID="EUR">20.00</Tax>
      <Category>
        <ID>S</ID>
        <Percent>21.000</Percent>
        <Description>
          <ID>Note</ID>
        </Description>
      </Category>
    </Total>
    <Total>
      <TotalAmount currencyID="EUR">200.00</TotalAmount>
      <Tax currencyID="EUR">0</Tax>
      <Category>
        <ID>O</ID>
        <Percent>0</Percent>
        <Description>
          <ID>Note</ID>
        </Description>
      </Category>
    </Total>
</root>
```

XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kByP" match="Category" use="ID"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:param name="pNewValue"/>
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*">
         <xsl:with-param name="pNewValue" select="$pNewValue"/>
       </xsl:apply-templates>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
   "Category[generate-id()
           =
            generate-id(key('kByP', ID)[1])
           ]">
  <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*">
         <xsl:with-param name="pNewValue" select=
         "sum(key('kByP', ID)/TotalAmount)"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="Total"/>

 <xsl:template match="TotalAmount/text()">
  <xsl:param name="pNewValue"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="$pNewValue"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Required output:

```
<root>
    <Total>
      <TotalAmount currencyID="EUR">250.00</TotalAmount>
      <Tax currencyID="EUR">40.00</Tax>
      <Category>
        <ID>S</ID>
        <Percent>21.000</Percent>
        <Description>
          <ID>Note</ID>
        </Description>
      </Category>
    </Total>
    <Total>
      <TotalAmount currencyID="EUR">200.00</TotalAmount>
      <Tax currencyID="EUR">0</Tax>
      <Category>
        <ID>O</ID>
        <Percent>0</Percent>
        <Description>
          <ID>Note</ID>
        </Description>
      </Category>
    </Total>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start with the identity transformation template plus the key you have changed to `<xsl:key name="kByP" match="Total" use="Category/ID"/>`, then have

```
<xsl:template match="Total[not(generate-id() = generate-id(key('kByP', Category/ID)[1]))]"/>
```

and then

```
<xsl:template match="TotalAmount | Tax">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('kByP', ../Category/ID)/*[name() = name(current())])"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

So the full code is

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
  
  <xsl:key name="kByP" match="Total" use="Category/ID"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="Total[not(generate-id() = generate-id(key('kByP', Category/ID)[1]))]"/>

  <xsl:template match="TotalAmount | Tax">
    <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
     <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(key('kByP', ../Category/ID)/*[name() = name(current())]), '0.00')"/>
   </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, i will try to figure it out. I do get some results now, but not the required data yet.

Comment: @keeskroket, https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bF2MmXa seems to have the right sums, I guess for to improve the number formatting you want to use e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(key('kByP', ../Category/ID)/*[name() = name(current())]), '0.00')"/>` but that is rather a cosmetic issue.

Comment: seems like it's working now. Thank Martin your last answer helped me a  lot.